# how to return static variable PHP

Tags: php, hierarchical-data

```
function build_path($cid)
{
    static $fr=array();
    $DB = new MySQLTable;
    $DB->TblName = 'shop_categories';
    $where['cat_id']['='] = $cid;
    $res = $DB->Select('cat_id,cat_name,cat_parent', $where);
    if($res !== false)
    {
        $pid = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        if($pid['cat_parent'] !== "0")
        {
           $fr[] = $pid['cat_id'];
           build_path($pid['cat_parent']);
        } else {
            $fr[] = $cid;
            $fr = array_reverse($fr);
            print_r($fr);
            return $fr;
        }
    }
}

print_r(build_path(100));
```

Why is working print_r in function, but second print_r returns NULL?

Comment: is it for sure going into the last else code block and executing return $fr?

Comment: ALL IS WORK. I was just moved return instruction to the end of function. THNKS 2 ALL!!!

Comment: I would post your final code as an answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, for a recursive function to work, you need to return something when calling itself.

Try this in your first nested if block:

```
return build_path($pid['cat_parent']);
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, You wouldn't need to write a recursive function or execute N queries for N levels of hierarchy if you used one of the various methods for storing hierarchical data in a database.

- [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)
- [Retrieving data with a hierarchical structure in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782525/retrieving-data-with-a-hierarchical-structure-in-mysql/2782653#2782653)
- [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Answer (score 0):

Recursive functions must not use `static` to pass the data through invokes - use the arguments instead.

And why do you need this line:

```
if($res !== false)
```

??

Comment: this class returns resource id if query is ok, and false if i have mysql error

Comment: @GOsha: if you write proper queries - you would never get mysql query error

Comment: If server is down it is better to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `build_path($pid['cat_parent']);` in line 14 use `return build_path($pid['cat_parent']);`.