# mysql - total count records in parent category

Tags: mysql

I have following table structure and data in MySQL

```
TABLE NAME : categories

CatID  CatName     ParentCatID
-------------------------------
1       Shirts        NULL
2       Short Sleev    1
3       Long Sleev     1
4       Collarless     2
5       Collar         2
6       Collarless     3
7       Collar         3
8       Square Cut     4
9       Round Cut      4
10      Square Cut     6
11      Round Cut      6

table name : companies
-------------------------------------------------
companyid |   company name | country | categoryid
-------------------------------------------------
1         |  Unitile ltd.  | India   |  5
2         |  abc ltd.      | India   |  2
3         |  infocom ltd.  | India   |  1
4         |  tata ltd.     | India   |  5
5         |  agro india    | India   |  1
```

I have 2 level of categories like : Shirts > Long Sleev

I want total records count under parent category like Shirts

Comment: Where is the question/problem? You just wrote done the fact, that you want the total record count.

Comment: sound like a hierarchical querys needed to me ? see this SO question for guidance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782525/retrieving-data-with-a-hierarchical-structure-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the companies table has to do with the problem. Something like this may do what you may be trying to achieive

```
SELECT 
C.CatID, COUNT(DISTINCT (IFNULL(PC.CatID, 0))) AS parentcategories
FROM categories C
LEFT JOIN categories PC ON (C.ParentCatID = PC.CatID)
GROUP BY C.CatID
;
```