# How to get all chidren's users in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name of users.

It contains following fields.

```
user_id  |  parent_user_id  | name
```

Consider my user_id is 5, I want to get the users who have parent_user_id 5 and its children and childrens of children and etc

How to get all children's of particular parent id?

Comment: So you mean you want to get everyone who has a id of 5? Give a quick example.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to do with php walking the tree?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive functions, so it is not well suited to the adjacency list model of storing hierarchical data (which you describe here). You ought to consider restructuring your data to use either nested sets or closure tables.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/623041) for more information.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2782653/259457

Comment: yes i want to retrieving data with a hierarchical structure

Comment: Honestly, most modern developers will use NoSQL data structures to store tree-like data structures.  It makes things much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it recursively. You can do it with `LEFT JOIN`s but you have to choose a maximum depth.

```
SELECT * FROM users u1
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u1.user_id = u2.parent_user_id
LEFT JOIN users u3 ON u2.user_id = u3.parent_user_id
WHERE u1.user_id = [SOME_USER_ID]
```

But as [Mike Brant suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198796/how-to-get-all-chidrens-users-in-mysql-table#comment16336923_12198796)  you might consider other alternatives such as [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Answer (score 0):

try something like that.

```
    SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE parent_user_id = "5" GROUP BY user_id
```

this will give all childs of the parent id is 5